# Transparent background color in TGroupBox - DELPHI

Tags: delphi, groupbox

How can i set transparent background color in TGroupBox?

In my Delphi's form I have a GroupBox and a Panel (graphically overlaid).
I wrote a procedure to draw a gradient fill on the Panel using Rect. It works!
Now I have another problem: GroupBox backgound color descends from the Form but I wish it was the same of Panel. I can't put GroupBox into Panel because draw procedure fill the entire Panel area (also GroupBox).
Is there a way (by code) to set trasparent background color of GroupBox?

Comment: Did you consider using FireMonkey? There you'd only have to set the `opacity` property

Comment: Yes, I consider it but for different reasons I decide to use a simple VCL Application.

Comment: I solved setting at runtime the Parent property of the GroupBox.

Comment: @stacker: If that **is** the answer than **post** it as answer and accept it.

Comment: @stacker: Why don't you make the relationship at design-time?

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt: If I make the relationship at design time when the draw procedure is performed the entire area of the Panel (included the GroupBox) will filled by the gradient and becomes invisible. So, at first i'm going to perform the draw procedure and then i set the Parent property of the GroupBox to Panel.

Comment: @stacker - You're performing the draw procedure in OnPaint of the form, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved setting at runtime the Parent property of the GroupBox.

Answer (score 0):

set parentcolor of the groupbox to true

Comment: ParentColor property is already set to True. But as I said the parent of the GroupBox is the Form not the Panel. I solved setting at runtime the Parent property of the GroupBox. So GroupBox take the background color of Panel.